# Template icons in the toolbar not visible in the Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I've prepared a template icon to be used in the toolbar and saved it in the PDF format. Then I set it as an image for the button in the toolbar. Unfortunately, it is not visible in Xcode, though it appears in the working application.

[image: The view in Xcode]
[image: Working application]

What might be the reason?